# Check if value entered has digits in it

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my program to check if the value entered for `password_entered` has a digit somewhere in it.

I currently have `c` that looks like:

```
int CFD(char password_entered[]);
int main()
{
    char password_entered[20]; //max is 20 char

    /*do{*/
        printf("password?? \n");
        scanf("%s", password_entered);

        if(CFD(password_entered))
        {
           //contains digit(s) character.
        }
        else{
           // no digits
        }


    /*}*/



    return 0;
}


int CFD(char password_entered[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++){

        if( isdigit(password_entered[i]) ){
            printf("\ndigit(s).\n");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nno digit(s).\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is, when i run my code, it keeps falling into the `else{}` what am I doing wrong here?

Part of the issue, if I enter in `3` it works, but not `John3` - how can i better evaluate this?

Thank you!

Comment: You are missing `isdigit` function.

Comment: you only check the first character of the password and immediately return from the function `CFD`

Comment: @Bitmap - look under CFD()

Comment: @Wimmel - how can i modify could to check any character inputted. If any inputted are digits, then say in if() else, go to else{}

Comment: You need `#include <string.h>`, `#include <ctype.h>`, `#include <stdio.h>`. Also please use `"%19s"` in scanf to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only test the first character of your password and then immediately return. Try this:

```
int CFD(char password_entered[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++) {
        if ( isdigit(password_entered[i]) ) {
            printf("\ndigit(s).\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\nno digit(s).\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you're saying the else{} is not needed?

Comment: Btw, this is not detecting a digit inputted if I put "Jenkins1"

Comment: @CodeTalk`else` in your code makes the function return immediately if first char is not a digit. It is not "not needed" it makes your code wrong in this case.

Comment: in C `return true` `return false` are not built in you have to include stdbool.h just to have that capability, I would recommend `return 1` and `return 0` instead.

Comment: @GRC - thanks for letting me know, stdbool is included.

Comment: You rock! Thank you so much, and you taught me a few things too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your CFD function does this

```
for each character in the password
    if that character is a digit
        then don't process any more characters, just return true
        otherwise don't process any more characters, just return false
```

Can you now see the problem? You can't know that none of the characters in the password are digits until you've looked at them all!

You actually want something like this:

```
for each character in the password
    if that character is a digit
        then don't process any more characters, just return true
if we get down here we know we've checked every character so return false
```

Comment: Can you show code? This is helpful, but, where am i returning true, then return false too?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would depend on the input you provide, but there IS a logical bug in your code...

Your `CFD` function "wants" to iterate over the password, but regardless of the type of character it finds, it immediately returns, and that happens while processing the first character.

To fix that, try like this:

```
int CFD(char password_entered[]){
    int i;
    int hasdigits = 0;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++){

        if( isdigit(password_entered[i]) ){
            printf("%c - digit\n", password_entered[i]);
            hasdigits = 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("%c - no digit\n", password_entered[i]);
        }
    }
    return hasdigits;
}
```

Or if you don't want printing, and want to stop as soon as possible:

```
int CFD(char password_entered[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++){

        if( isdigit(password_entered[i]) ){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, regardless of what solution you choose, repeatedly calling `strlen` is wasteful. You can either "go backwards", or use a variable to hold the length like this: `int i, l; for(i=0,l=strlen(password_entered); i<l; i++)`.

Comment: for second solution up, for the first one down  1 + -1 = 0 :). I do not like that you are creating additional variable just for return.

Comment: @GRC, would you like to suggest a different method - assuming you do want to print for each character?

Comment: Ohhh, I think I see what you mean.. I didn't even pay attention to the printed text :-) It obviously makes no sense to print that...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, below:

```
int CFD(char password_entered[]){
int i;
for(i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++){

    if( isdigit(password_entered[i]) ){
        printf("\ndigit(s).\n");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        printf("\nno digit(s).\n");
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

the return statement in each of if and else returns from the CFD function immediately. Regardless of whether the first character is a digit, the function reads only the first character.

The "textbook" solution to this sort of problem is to "only return from a single place in any function." This can be achieved by assigning a return value within the if and else, then returning it at the end of the funation, after the for loop. This is Amit's first solution, and it is a good one.

You're on the right track though, when you say (in your comment above) that the else is not needed... you could also do this (return false normally, only return true if a digit is found):

```
int CFD(char password_entered[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++) {
        if(is digit(password_entered[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```